# How do I create dialog boxes in Jira?

Tags: groovy, dialog, jira

I have written a groovy script for cloning issues on a transition step in Jira. The script works fine in the background and creates the required cloned issue.

I want a dialog box to appear on the screen confirming the cloned issue's name before actually cloning the issue.

How do I create such dialog boxes?

Comment: [I assume you've seen this](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Displaying+Content+in+a+Dialog+in+JIRA) which is the second link when you google `JIRA API Dialog`

Answer (score 3):

Consider looking at the **Dialog** pattern in the [AUI Sandbox](https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/latest/sandbox/).

Here's a very simple example...

**HTML:**

```
<button id="dialog-button" class="aui-button">Show dialog</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var dialog = new AJS.Dialog({
    id: "example-dialog", 
    closeOnOutsideClick: false
});

dialog.addHeader("Dialog");
dialog.addPanel("Panel 1", "<p>Some content for panel 1.</p>", "panel-body");

dialog.addButton("OK", function (dialog) {
    dialog.hide();
}, "#");

// add behaviour to the "Show Dialog" button
AJS.$("#dialog-button").click(function() {
    dialog.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a far easier way to do this that doesn't require any custom scripting in either AUI or Sandbox. Add a custom field called something like "I understand that I am transitioning this issue" and add it to a custom screen (could be called "Transition Confirmation". Then add this screen to the transition and add a validator that makes the above mentioned field mandatory in this specific transition. Done! :)